# Stalk at isolated point of proper map with $f_*\mathcal{O}_X=\mathcal{O}_Y$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $f:X \to Y$ a proper surjective map between schemes $X,Y$ with additional assumption $f_*\mathcal{O}_X=\mathcal{O}_Y$. Let $y \in Y$ with a 'isolated point fiber', i.e., $f^{-1}(y)=\{x\}$ as set. By assumption we have $(f_*\mathcal{O}_X)_y=\mathcal{O}_{Y,y}$, i.e., the fibers are geometrically connected.

**Q:** Is there a 'relative elementary' (cp with Rmk #3 below) way to see that $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}=\mathcal{O}_{Y,y}$ holds?

A couple of remarks:
Rmk. #1: [Here](https://amathew.wordpress.com/2010/12/24/the-second-version-of-zariskis-main-theorem/) is given seemingly a proof of this statement, which I do not fully understand. There it is argued that this should immediately follow because $U$ is a "small" neighborhood of $y$, then $f^{-1}(U)$ is "small" neighborhood of $x$. What is meant here precisely by  "small" neighborhood? What distinguishes them from usual open subsets containing the point? And why would this imply the claim?

(a naïve guess: maybe by "small" is meant that it is contained in certain *affine* neighborhood of the point. But if that's the case, why this holds also for the preimages $f^{-1}(U)$?)

Rmk. #2: If $Y$ would be integral and $y=\eta_Y$ the generic point, then the claim should follow from proper base change theorem due to flatness of $\{y\} \to Y$ (somewhere in Hartshorne Chap. III, the flatness part)

Rmk. #3: In Q. Liu's "Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves" the problem is solved in more general setting without "properness" assumption using techniques on formal schemes (Prop 4.4.2). So this is seemingly the price to pay. But I'm wondering as I stated above if - when we add the properness assumption - it is possible to argue using a more elementary argument without passing to completions as auxiliary step. That's what I meant above with more 'elementary'.

Comment: Rmk 1 here means that for any open subscheme $V$ of $X$ containing $x$, there is an open subscheme $U$ of $Y$ containing $y$ such that $f^{-1}(U) \subset V$. Proof: let $V$ be as above. Then the image $Z$ in $Y$ of $X \backslash V$ is a closed subset (by properness) not containing $y$. Let $U$ be its complement, which is open. Then $f^{-1}(U) \subset V$.

Comment: @Aphelli: right I see, so - in this special situation assumping properness - the open subsets of the form $f^{-1}(U)$, where $U$ open containing $y$ are cofinal in the direct system of all opens $V$ containing $x$ due to your argument - and therefore the colimits over all $O_X(V)$ and over  $O_X(f^{-1}(U))$ coinside. But the former colimit is the stalk at $x$. Alright, thanks.